# Extra "Nice Answer" Badge and "Good Answer"?

Tags: support, badges

I've noticed that Super User has [granted me](https://superuser.com/users/1086/john-rudy) two "Nice Answer" badges.

Yet I can only see one answer of my own which would appear to qualify. Additionally, I seem to have a "Good Answer" badge on Super User which I do not appear to deserve at all. :)

Checking the vote counts on the other highest-voted answers I have there, it doesn't appear to be a case where I had an answer that was upvoted above 10, then downvoted below. Ditto (naturally) the 25-vote threshold for "Good Answer."

Do I have answers which were perhaps deleted (or on questions which were deleted/migrated) that garnered the requisite upvotes for these badges? Do I merely "owe" the system them?

Comment: I would have thought the +10 -2 for either the font recognition or Mozilla answer is the most likely. I lack the rep on SU to find out, though.

Comment: @Marc no, they're both +8, no downvotes for either of them. It is strange, you should not have the badge twice. Could a question have been migrated along with your answer?

Comment: It's most likely that the question was deleted or migrated, and you now "owe" the system a badge as you say.

Comment: @ChrisF: That's what I'm thinking. @Marc: That was my gut reaction too, until I checked as @alex did. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have provided two answers that have ≥10 [upvotes](https://superuser.com/users/1086/john-rudy#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_votes-asort_votes), which matches the badge qualification.

[image: answers]
[image: badges]

---

As for Good Answer, the answer had probably been migrated/deleted. Badges, once awarded, generally [are not revoked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work).

Answer (score 0):

Also there may be a "Not Exact Answer" or "Unrelated Answer", etc. For example there is an answer to this question [Is there a way to move taskbar items to the system tray?](https://superuser.com/questions/16388/is-there-a-way-to-move-taskbar-items-to-the-system-tray) : [Is there a way to move taskbar items to the system tray?](https://superuser.com/questions/16388/is-there-a-way-to-move-taskbar-items-to-the-system-tray/16445#16445)